# catch fail cases during bulk_update Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I have an input file of 10k entries & I divide it into smaller chunks. for each chunk I want to perform a bulk_update operation in Django.

However, I also want to log if there is any failed update case, due to any reason, and let the update continue. How can I achieve that?

Also, does django stop the bulk update query upon encountering an error in the input chunk or does it ignore & continue?

Comment: First, please describe the purpose of your _bulk_ update.  It is generally wrong (or at least inefficient) to need to update more than a few rows at a time.  The info may help in finding a solution or a workaround.

Comment: I need to bulk update a certain column in db against all the records in a chunk. Assuming that bulk update is very efficient for may case, since my entries might be even more than 10k, I just need a mechanism to store logs. @RickJames

Comment: Do you have some examples of "failed update case"?

Comment: The question is what errors you expect to happen during the bulk update. In general you should validate your data before getting into db business, as the db (bulk) functions are only a very thin abstraction above SQL (either with django validators or your very own type/range checks). The db adapter can still throw errors from integrity issues or type violations - you can catch these with transactions. For bulk_update this will undo the whole batch where the error happened, from there you can loop step to the faulty entry.